# How to stop/start css animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

## How to stop/start CSS animation

### Background-Info

I'm trying to make a loader for my website where when someone makes a search to my API it will popup the loader then after the table gets built it will stop the loading animation. I'm not good with javascript and I'm just trying to create this side project so I don't completely know how this stuff works. I did see another stack overflow post about this topic but it didn't apply to me because the way they called the CSS animation was different

I followed a tutorial for this loader [here](https://youtu.be/wwJcYaJg8Mc) he shows how to stop it but he doesn't show how to start it, but it doesn't stop for me

---

### What I tried

Like I was saying above I'm not good with javascript so I wasn't sure what i should try but like in the video I tried to make the CSS display = None and also i tried to remove the HTML entirely ( you can see it below in the code)

### End goal

My end goal is to have a javascript function like `start_loading()` and `stop_loading()` I can call to stop and start the loading at any time

---

### Code

```js
function start_load() {
  let spinnerWrapper = document.querySelector('.spinner-wrapper')
  console.log(document.querySelector('.spinner-wrapper'))
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    spinnerWrapper.style.display = 'none';
    // spinnerWrapper.parentElement.removeChild(spinnerWrapper)
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.spinner-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* background-color: #151515; */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.spinner {
  position: relative;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 8rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.spinner::before,
.spinner:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.spinner:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #212529 0%, white 100%);
  animation: spin .5s infinite linear;
}

.spinner:after {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: white;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@keyframes spin {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}


/*Simulate page content*/

.main-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("https://source.unsplash.com/random/4000x4000") center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body onload="verifySession(), start_load()">
  <div class="spinner-wrapper">
    <div class="spinner">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: well first I would use the `eventListener`. When do you want to stop the loading?

Comment: You could put the animations inside a css class and add/remove them as you wish with js?

Comment: The `startload()` event handler looks like it's ending everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear on when you want to start and stop the loader but from my understanding you have an api and you want the loader to show when someone  calls your api so in this particular case you want to work with DOM event listeners *(at least when you start your search by a click of a button or when you press enter on your keyboard)* you can read more on event listeners here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener and here:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

As for stopping the event you will want to call the stop function once data are returned from your API

I've created a little codesandbox for you with two buttons to start and stop the loader as a simple example of how to use event listeners which you can find here: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-rain-e9w3mz

Comment: This worked best for me thanks for making it simple and linking a sand box

Answer (score 1):

```
const start_load = function () {
    document.querySelector('.spinner-wrapper').style.display = "block"
}

const end_load= function () {
    document.querySelector('.spinner-wrapper').style.display = "none"
}
```

You can change .spinner-wrapper by any class you want. Those function will set fisrt html tag have .spinner-wrapper class to display : block or display : none
Hope this help for you